# Imagick not found via CMD only?

Tags: php, imagick

There are plenty of windows imagic headaches around the web.
I did find the right combination of everything and it got working.

However
when i start php from command line it spits out a warning:

**Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0**

How can the damn thing work, use the files that are verified to be there and have an apache server running based on them files, but throw a failure at launch?

Here is the relevant php.ini section should you need to look it over:
(should you have no idea how to make it find it - is there a way to disable the startup warning and error popups that it throws at me, they break my cmd scripts.)

```
extension_dir="c:\xampp\php\ext"

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename.extension
;
; For example, on Windows:
;
;   extension=msql.dll
;
; ... or under UNIX:
;
;   extension=msql.so
;
; ... or with a path:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/msql.so
;
; If you only provide the name of the extension, PHP will look for it in its
; default extension directory.
;
; Windows Extensions
; Note that ODBC support is built in, so no dll is needed for it.
; Note that many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) ext/ (PHP 5)
; extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5).
; Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.


extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
;extension=php_mssql.dll
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll      ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client

extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite_external.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll

; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed. 
; See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php 
;extension=php_snmp.dll

extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_sockets.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_xsl.dll

extension=php_mongo.dll
extension=php_imagick.dll
```

Comment: just because the files are there doesn't mean they're actually useable. MANY of those php plugin .dlls are compiled with different compilers/parameters than php itself, leaving php unable to load the library.

Comment: Except the page is generating the images i want generated via imagic.And the phpinfo detects the imagick as a working plugin and lists the supported formats.

Comment: A colleague solved it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the Imagic CORE_RL_*.DLLs have a pathing problem.
The full setup i was using was calling them from their config location but should you just start an unrelated php via cmd it failed to find them:

To solve it copy all your core dlls from your imagick install dir allover the place namingly to:

1. Your **php main dir**
2. Your **\xampp\apache\bin**

(2. Is should you be using xampp or apache obviously.)

Comment: Well, thank you for the response. I've lost time figuring why it works under Apache and not via php command line. Then i found your response. I've copied all files from Imagick zip, image conversion didn't work only with CORE_RL_*.DLL I was getting the "NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat" error. PHP 7.3.7

Comment: @helena4 thanks for this answer, been going crazy about this for 2 hours already